# no such command: 'shardCollection'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

my mongo-java-driver version is 3.12.10
mongodb version is 6.0.4，and a sharded cluster is deployed
Execute the following command in the java program to report an error
`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: 'shardCollection'' on server xxx:27018. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: 'enableSharding'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound", "lastCommittedOpTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1688634311, "i": 1}}, "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1688634317, "i": 3}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1688634311, "i": 1}}}`

this is my command
`Document append = new Document("shardCollection", new BsonString(dataBase + "." + collect)).append("key", new Document("_id", "hashed")); admin.runCommand(append);`

Is the reason for this error because mongo-driver does not support fragmentation?
Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`shardCollection` is a [helper](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/sh.shardCollection/) specific only to mongo shell, not mongo drivers. You can't run it from the driver. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268475/programmatically-set-shard-key-with-mongodb-java-driver) or my answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014860/running-custom-commands-in-mongodb-node-driver/72016129#72016129)